# Can't get my font awesome icons to appear is it because I'm using xampp

Tags: html, font-awesome

This is the code for the site I'm trying to make and there are to main problem i'm having i have to clear my web cache every time I search something and the second being that font-awesome icon wont show up

````
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;300;400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Home.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/yourcode.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
    <nav>
        <input type="checkbox" id-"check">
        <label for="check">
            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </label>
        <label class="logo"> Logo</label>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="Projects.html">PROJECTS</a></li>
            <li><a href="Contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the Font Awesome issue, have a look at the link in your script. You have it set to a placeholder link which doesn't lead anywhere. You need to replace where it says "yourcode" with your Font Awesome account's kit code. See here: https://www.w3schools.com/icons/fontawesome5_intro.asp